# How to Update IconicTile & LockScreen defined by WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I'm trying to create an IconicTile for Windows Phone 8. I've defined with VS2012 the type of Tile Template to TemplateIconic and added a Tile Title and two images for small and medium.

If I pin my app to the start screen, I can choose between small and medium tiles like expected.

Now I want to update the IconicTile I defined in my WMAppManifest.xml. As I understand IconicTile, it needs to be updated in code and will also update the LockScreen icon and count, if I defined one. I've added a DeviceLockImageURI and this Extensions:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Notification_IconCount" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default"/>
  <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Notification_TextField" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

**First question: Is this ConsumerID always the same or which ID is it?**

To update the IconicTile I've defined in WMAppManifest.xml, I need to get hold of any pinned Tiles of my Application on the screen. I've read a lot of tutorials explaining how to add tiles manually from your application, but I only want to use the tile I've defined in WMAppManifest.xml. Therefore all tutorials recommended to get the current active Tile with this code:

```
ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
```

ActiveTiles is an IEnumeration and only offers me: Equals, GetEnumerator, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString

**Second question: What am I missing here? Does FirstOrDefault only work for FlipTiles or CycleTiles? I only want to use the IconicTile!**

So I'm stuck at identifying the current active IconicTile on the screen, so that I can use an IconicTileData object to update the count or text of the IconicTile. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question:**

I've [seen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) a Tile ID when you create an IconicTile from Xml:

```
<wp:Tile Id="[Tile ID]" Template="IconicTile">
```

Maybe it is this ID? Otherwise I'll go with allways the same static ID, as there is no documentation on how to create this ID.

**For the second question:**

I've found the error: I was missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

This using enables access to the Linq Methods necessary to use FirstOrDefault or similar commands. I was mislead by

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

which is definitevly not the same Linq class ;)